# How do I write a SPARQL query for this

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, semantic-web

How do i write a SPARQL query to retrieve all the movies and co-directors of a movie having director with name "George".

triples are

```
@prefix : <http://org.example/> .

:movie1 :hasDirectors :d1, :d2, :d3 .
:movie2 :hasDirectors :d3, :d4 .
:movie3 :hasDirectors :d1, :d3

:d1 :name "George" .
:d2 :name "Jack" .
:d6 :name "Raj" .
:d3 :name "Henry" .
:d4 :name "Williams" .
```

Comment: so, what did you try so far? I mean, we can't do the whole thing for you, if you don't understand SPARQL at all. That wouldn't be helpful. You should at least be able to query for *"directors with name "George" "* which is just a single triple pattern. Then append the path to the movie by another triple pattern, then one to get all directors of this movie and finally you'll need a filter to exclude "George" from the co-directors.

Comment: PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://org.example/>
SELECT ?movie ?name WHERE {
  ?movie :hasDirectors ?d.
  ?d :name ?name.
  FILTER(?name="George").
} 
I get all the movies with director "George" using this query

Comment: well, so you are almost there: `SELECT ?movie ?name ?coDirectors WHERE { ?movie :hasDirectors ?d. ?d :name "George".  ?movie :hasDirectors ?coDirectors . FILTER(?coDirectors != "George") }`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I modified it a bit to give me the names of coDirectors. ```SELECT ?movie ?name ?coDirectors_name WHERE { ?movie :hasDirectors ?d. ?d :name ?name. FILTER(?name="George")
  ?movie :hasDirectors ?coDirectors . ?coDirectors :name ?coDirectors_name
  FILTER(?coDirectors_name != "George") }```

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the comments the query should be as follows:

```
SELECT ?movie ?name ?coDirectors_name WHERE { ?movie :hasDirectors ?d. ?d :name ?
name. FILTER(?name="George") ?movie :hasDirectors ?coDirectors . ?coDirectors :name 
?coDirectors_name FILTER(?coDirectors_name != "George") }
```